# django missing csrf token in javascript .submit() function (non ajax)

Tags: javascript, django, csrf-token

I am using a javascript to send an html form to django.
js looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("fooform").submit();
```

and the html form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="fooform" action ="{% url 'foo:doo' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" id="fooinput" value="" />
</form>
```

the js can write the data into the input field without any problems and also carry out the submit. my problem is using the crsf token.
I have already put the token `{% csrf_token %}` in every conceivable place. (Before the form, before the js...). in the html code is the token also correct.

django gives me the error:

```
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

    Your browser is accepting cookies.
    The view function passes a request to the template's render method.
    In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
    If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
    The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.

You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

---

Edit:
The view.py:

```
def foo_view(request):
    print(request.POST)
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'foo'
urlpatterns = \
    [
        path('doo', views.foo_view, name='foo_view'),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the view that handles the form POST please

Comment: i added the view.py and the urls.py in the main post

Answer (score 0):

Your action is `"{% url 'foo:doo' %}"` But in your urls path name is `foo_view`